# Mockito, @InjectMocks strange behaviour with final fields

Tags: java, testng, mockito

I am seeing behaviour that I believe is a bug. @InjectMocks does not seem to create a new test subject before every test method. Where as @Mock does. In the following example, if Subject.section is final one @Test fails. If its not final both pass. My current workaround is to use @BeforeClass, but this is not ideal.

Subject.java:

```
package inject_mocks_test;
public class Subject {

    private final Section section;

    public Subject(Section section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public Section getSection() {
        return section;
    }
}
```

Section.java:

```
package inject_mocks_test;

public class Section {}
```

SubjectTest.java

```
package inject_mocks_test;

import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SubjectTest {

    @Mock
    Section section;

    @InjectMocks
    Subject subject;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertEquals(section, subject.getSection());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        assertEquals(section, subject.getSection());        
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: are you using MockitoJUnitRunner for running the test case?

Comment: No I am using TestNg.

Comment: which version of mockito do you use?

Comment: mockito version is 1.9.5

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are using the `@InjectMocks` for **constructor** injection. This will work as long as Mockito finds the field not initalized (null). JUnit is creating a new instance of the test class before each test, so JUnit fans (like me) will never face such problem. TestNg is not creating a new instance of test class. It's keeping the state between test methods, so when `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` is called for the second time, Mockito will find *subject* field already initialized and will try to use **field** injection. This on the other turn will work until the field is not final.

Is this is a bug? I believe not - rather a natural consequence of the API design.
Some workaround for you would be to add

```
this.subject = null;
```

in some `@AfterMethod` method.

Comment: Thanks, that does work too. But I don't understand why section is reinitialized but subject isn't.

Comment: It's for backward compatibility. In earlier versions (<= 1.8.5) only setter injection was supported and you needed an instance to be provided by you [see docs](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.5/javadoc/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html). So now, when mockito sees that you have an instance already created it's not trying to reinitialize it's just trying setter or field injection.

Comment: ...on the other hand there could be an enhancement to parametrize the InjectMocks with smth like *forceReinitializaton*. I also found [this](https://github.com/skabashnyuk/mockitong/releases) a TestNG integration for mockito. It's not released yet - maybe it will reset the InjectMocks fields.

Comment: Alternatively it maybe interesting to use the classes [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/tree/release/2.x/subprojects/testng/src/main/java/org/mockito/testng), it allows avoid the boilerplate code to manage the lifecycle of mocks on annotated fields.

Comment: In my case re-setting the mock field in the AfterMethod method didn't work. So I had to make the field not final in the class declaration