# Mockito when not resetting between Tests

Tags: java, mockito

Right now I am simulating two successful requests and then three different exceptions when a method is called by chaining them all together.

```
        when(mockActivity.enact(any(RegisterRequest.class)))
           .thenReturn(successfulRequest, nonSuccessfulRequest)
           .thenThrow(RecoverableException.class, UnrecoverableException.class, InvalidRequestException.class);
```

Ideally, this could be split up into 5 different @Test methods (2 that don't throw exceptions, and 3 that do throw exceptions) each with a `when(mockActivity.enact(any(RegisterRequest.class))).thenReturn or thenThrow(...)`. But when I try to do that the previous @Test mocks will interfere with one another.

I scanned stack overflow and I thought I would be able to reset based off

```
    @Mock
    private RegisterActivity mockRegisterActivity;
    @InjectMocks
    private RegisterAZActivity registerAZActivity;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

But it doesn't appear to truly be resetting. The flow is `RegisterAZActivity` is the test I'm testing, and `RegisterAZActivity` calls `RegisterActivity`, a private member, and that can return either 2 variations of successful requests or throw 3 different exceptions. So ideally I could test that method in 5 tests, each with it's own `when()` to test all possible routes. I tried using `Mockito.reset` and `BeforeMethod` but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Are you using TestNG?

Comment: Yes I am! Mixture of mockit, testng, and junit.

Comment: First things first - `initMocks` is deprecated. Switch to the test listener or at least `openMocks`. But to fix your problem, set `registerAZActivity` to `null` in an `@AfterMethod`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056622/2071828

Comment: Thank you so much! that solved it and will do.